# Android - How can I capture a camera preview frame after autoFocus is ready?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to capture a camera preview frame only when `camera.autoFocus(AutoFocusCallback callback)` is successful. How can i do it? 
Is there a way to capture frame within `onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera)` method?
What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
public void butClick(View v){
    preview.camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            if(success){
                //capturing frame...
            }
        }
    });
```

Please note that I don't wanna take a picture, but just capture a frame to convert then in a Mat object, which will be processed by opencv.
Any samples would be much appreciated. Thank you

}

Answer (score 0):

I am using android.hardware.camera (which is deprecated but required for my project) to do my frame grabbing. In order to grab preview frames you need to hookup a callback to the camera preview callback. see [Android CameraPreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) for more info.

Ex:

`camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
     public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
         // Process the contents of byte for whatever you need
     }
});`

The frame is access by the byte[]. You will need to convert this on your own. If you need to decode it to a viewable format I recommend checking out [Decode YUV data](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=823#c4) for some tips.

NOTE: This callback gets called for every frame that is displayed. So you will either need to stop the preview using `camera.stopPreview()` or some other logic. Since camera.stopPreview() will stop the camera from updating to the user.

Handling camera frame data is tricky to setup but once you get it working, its powerful. Goodluck and reply if you need anymore details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "grab" a frame from the camera synchronously. But the delay is hopefully quite short and the frame will be in focus. From the onAutoFocus() callback you can call [camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)).